# Values of arguments to waitpid when calling it with a single argument without including sys/wait.h

Tags: c, assembly

Consider the following C program:

```
int main()
{
    waitpid(1337);
}
```

As expected, gcc and clang both warn me about the implicit declaration of waitpid but the resulting binary works fine. When `ltrace`-ing it, I see that

```
waitpid(1337, 0x7fff86950ec8, -2037051688)
```

is called. Now three questions:

1. why does the above C code even work? I should have to include `sys/wait.h` to be able to call waitpid. The same thing happens when calling `printf` and not including `stdio.h`. The output works.
2. so gcc does some magic to still call waitpid, but why is it possible to call it with only one argument even though it has three? Calling `ltrace` multiple times hints that the other two arguments are random values? Gcc does some translation between one-argument waitpid and three-argument waitpid but how?
3. how can I use gdb to figure out the values behind the last two arguments? The other two values do not show up in the sourcecode so how do I access them in gcc?

Some clues I gathered: I looked at the assembler output of the main function:

```
0x000000000040050c <+0>:    push   %rbp
0x000000000040050d <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000000400510 <+4>:    mov    $0x539,%edi
0x0000000000400515 <+9>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040051a <+14>:   callq  0x4003f0 <waitpid@plt>
0x000000000040051f <+19>:   pop    %rbp
0x0000000000400520 <+20>:   retq
```

So I guess it's not gcc that does something because there indeed seems to be a waitpid function which takes exactly one argument (the 1337)?

Comment: Generally speaking the only thing a compiler has to do when it encounters undefined behavior is to issue a "diagnostic". Never ignore warnings of C compilers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does the above C code even work?

It "works" by chance. C allows you to call a function without specifying its prototype, i.e. without including its header. When you do that it **makes assumptions about the number and types of arguments** and tries to call it. Obviously, calling a function with the wrong number of arguments is undefined behavior.

> 6.5.2.2-3
>
> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
>   each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to
>   double. These are called the default argument promotions. **If the
>   number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters**, the
>   behavior is undefined.

As for your third question, I suspect the garbage you are seeing is just leftovers on the stack. To find out if that's true, put a breakpoint before the `waitpid` and then step into it and see what gets passed.

Answer (score 0):

By including the header file in a c program you are basically giving the prototype of the function. If it is not given then it assumes the number of arguments and type of arguments as told by cnicutar. It also assumes that the return type of a function is int if the prototype is not defined.